# Mockito verify skip a number of calls?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, verify

I want to check the parameter passed to a method ... but the check has to be done on the 3rd time this method gets called.

I thought the answer might be to go:

```
verify( myMock, times( 2 ) ).myMethod( any() );
verify( myMock ).myMethod( paramIWant );
```

... but it fails on the first line:

> But was 5 times. Undesired invocation:

... because there are indeed 2 more calls after the one I'm interested in.

Comment: Thanks.  I've used ArgumentCaptor a bit before. I was hoping there might be a snappy way to do it!

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything that's snappier than my answer.  You can, of course, use an annotation to create your captor, if you feel so inclined.

Comment: "But was 5 times." is because the `any()` Matcher used in the 1st verify is greedy and matches all method invocations. It has no idea that there are other verify calls with other matchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an argument captor for this.  You can pass the captor in when you verify, then get out all the values that were passed as a parameter to this method and check whichever you want.

```
ArgumentCaptor<SomeClass> myCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(SomeClass.class);
verify(myMock,times(5)).myMethod(myCaptor.capture());

List<SomeClass> paramsPassed = myCaptor.getAllValues();
assertEquals(paramIWant, paramsPassed.get(2));
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Very snappy, great.  As a newb at Mockito, most of my activity is confined to use of one class, `Mockito`.  But there are hundreds of other classes and I sometimes wonder what they do... for example the classes which implement `VerificationMode` (i.e. 2nd param of `verify`).  All will become clear in the course of time, no doubt.

Comment: PS I ***think*** you've missed sthg out here, so I shall attempt an edit... if I've got it wrong, apologies.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for spotting that.  I _always_ forget that part.